# How to share data between components, by global mixins in vuejs ? why it is not reactive?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-mixin

I want to share simple data between all components
I know it can be done using `Vuex` or a global variable as a state, but it's overkill for my project!

Here is the code:

```
Vue.mixin({
    data: function () {
        return {
            base_url: 'http://test.develop/api/v1/',
            isLoading : false
        }
    }
})
```

`base_url` is constant and its working but `isLoading` must be reactive and it is not working, when I change it in one component and log it in another, it remains unchanged.

Now my question is what kind of data should be used in vue mixins ? Are mixins only for sharing code or data can be shared by mixins too?

Comment: Mixins are a bad idea; use vuex.

Comment: We consider this approach as practical and a good trade-off in our project. Our state is rather simple but there would be many (many many) mutations and actions to the state. I think it might be a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Vuex will probably not be overkill. Vuex works great for small and large projects. Vue mixins are not meant for keeping global state. Mixins are the OOP equivalent of extends. You basically inherit everything that's on it through a merge, with the component having priority. It's just for shared behavior (methods, data, lifecycle).

**Disclaimer**: I can't think of this being accepted in the community, just take it as a learning exercise.

But the only way to have a 'global state' of sorts kept within a mixin, is to wrap its initialization object in a closure, and keep track of the information in a reactive object, like so:

```
Vue.mixin((()=>{
  let store = Vue.observable({
    isLoading: true
  })

  return {
    computed: {
      isLoading: {
        get(){
          return store.isLoading
        },
        set(val){
          store.isLoading = val
        }
      }
    },
  }
})())
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cuzox/ptsh283w/

Again, I'm not endorsing this method

Comment: Just need to stress that mixins are a terrible idea; have an upvote for answering the question though haha

Comment: How about constant data? what is the best way to share constant data like `base_url` between all components?

Comment: Typically you'd use "Environment Variables" for things like URL, just because if it's in dev mode you'd be in localhost, but if you're deployed you'd have an actual URL, and you wouldn't want to manually change it